# Android emulator failed to open Ionic2 app

Tags: android-emulator, ionic2

- App working fine.
- Ionic serve also working.
- App running in the android mobile wothout any error.

**Problem with emulator only !**

[SampleImage.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/501XD.png)